# Design pattern for implementing hooks in form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Coming from a class background, form components were designed something on the lines of -

```
class Test extends Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        //10 more variables
    }

    handleInputChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.name} />
                {/* 10  more inputs */}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

where `handleInputChange` could be re-used across all further input additions, if the variable of the state had the same definition as the name of the input element.

Now, where I am facing a difficulty in deciding is that what is the best approach  for this use-case in the hooks design pattern. So, porting this behaviour in hooks --

```
function Test() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  //10 more variables

  handleNameChange(e) {
        setName(e.target.value);
  }

  //similar 10 more functions

  return (
    <>
        <input name="name" onChange={handleNameChange} value={name} />
        {/* 10 more inputs */}
    </>
  );
}
```

The given snippet above, would eventually require defining 10 functions to set value of each variable separately.

Function declaration can be reduced, but I feel it'll make the code look unreadable, eg -

```
handleInputChange(e) {
   const functionName = e.target.name;
   functionName(e.target.value);
}
```

To drill down the scope of this thread, what will be the most gracious approach to handle multiple similar elements ( like inputs ) in react-hooks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replicate the 'shallow merging' behavior of `this.setState` with hooks, you can use a single `useState` with an [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). This can be expressed quite consisely using the object spread syntax:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({ name: '' });

function handleInputChange(e) {   
    setState(prevState => {
        return { ...prevState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    });
}
```

Or alternatively, if you don't want to use syntax that isn't standardized yet:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({ name: '' });

function handleInputChange(e) {   
    setState(prevState => {
        return Object.assign({}, prevState, { [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    });
}
```

You may also want to consider trying [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) - I've found that tends to be better at handling complex state updates.